# How to keep previously opened .tex files open while I start winedt

Tags: latex

I am working on a report and my document class is report. I work with multiple chapters and would like WinEdt reopens all the files from my previous session. Till yesterday it was like that but after clicking new project menu, which was accidental, winedt stopped opening files from my previous session. Please help me to figure this out as I work with more than ten .tex file for my report, and related tasks and opening all these .tex files, from different location, is tedious plus now I lose the continuity of my work.

Comment: Maybe better suited for superuser.com ?

Comment: Thank you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz. I will ask the question there.